# Execute Functions on an Interval Basis C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduling, saving-data

So I have a Kinect program that has three main functions that collect data and saves it. I want one of these functions to execute as much as possible, while the other two run maybe 10 times every second.

```
while(1)
{ 
...
//multi-threading to make sure color and depth events are aligned -> get skeletal data
        if (WaitForSingleObject(colorEvent, 0) == 0 && WaitForSingleObject(depthEvent, 0) == 0)
        {
            std::thread first(getColorImage, std::ref(colorEvent), std::ref(colorStreamHandle), std::ref(colorImage));
            std::thread second(getDepthImage, std::ref(depthEvent), std::ref(depthStreamHandle), std::ref(depthImage));
            if (WaitForSingleObject(skeletonEvent, INFINITE) == 0)
            {
                first.join();
                second.join();

                std::thread third(getSkeletonImage, std::ref(skeletonEvent), std::ref(skeletonImage), std::ref(colorImage), std::ref(depthImage), std::ref(myfile));
                third.join();
            }
            //if (check == 1)
            //check = 2;
        }
}
```

Currently my threads are making them all run at the same exact time, but this slows down my computer a lot and I only need to run 'getColorImage' and 'getDepthImage' maybe 5-10 times/second, whereas 'getSkeletonImage' I would want to run as much as possible.

I want 'getSkeletonImage' to run at max frequency (~30 times/second through the while loop) and then the 'getColorImage' and 'getDepthImage' to time synchronize (~5-10 times/second through the while loop)

What is a way I can do this? I am already using threads, but I need one to run consistently, and then the other two to join in intermittently essentially. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your main loop is *creating* the threads every iteration, which suggests each thread function runs once to completion.   That introduces the overhead of creating and destroying threads every time.

Personally, I wouldn't bother with threads at all.   Instead, in the main thread I'd do

```
void RunSkeletonEvent(int n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        //   wait required time   (i.e. to next multiple of 1/30 second)
        skeletonEvent();
    }
}

// and, in your main function ....

while (termination_condition_not_met)
{
    runSkeletonEvent(3);
    colorEvent();
    runSkeletonEvent(3);
    depthEvent();
}
```

This interleaves the events, so `skeletonEvent()` runs six times for every time `depthEvent()` and `colorEvent()` are run.   Just adjust the numbers as needed to get required behaviour.

You'll need to design the code for all the events so they don't run over time (if they do, all subsequent events will be delayed - there is no means to stop that).

The problem you'll then need to resolve is how to wait for the time to fire the skeleton event.   A process of retrieving clock time, calculating how long to wait, and sleeping for that interval will do it.    By sleeping (the thread yielding its time slice) your program will also be a bit better mannered (e.g. it won't be starving other processes of processor time).

One advantage is that, if data is to be shared between the "events" (e.g. all of the events modify some global data) there is no need for synchronisation, because the looping above guarantees that only one "event" accesses shared data at one time.

Note:   your usage of `WaitForSingleObject()` indicates you are using windows.   Windows (except, arguably CE in a weak sense) is not really a realtime system, so does not guarantee precise timing.   In other words, the actual intervals you achieve will vary.

It is still possible to restructure to use threads.  From your description, there is no evidence you really need anything like that, so I'll leave this reply at that.